# Ember.js - CollectionView, add an attribute to the div wrapper of the child view

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to combine two ebmer.js examples: [Integrating with jQuery UI](http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/) and the [todos example from emberjs.com](http://emberjs.com/examples/). I want to have a todo list that is sortable.

Everything went smooth until I got to a point where I wanted to serialize the sortable. For that to work, I need to be able to add an attribute to the sortable items.
this is the template:

```
{{#collection Todos.TodosListView}}
    {{#view Todos.TodoView contentBinding="content" checkedBinding="content.isDone"}}
        <label>{{content.title}}</label>
    {{/view}}
{{/collection}}
```

`Todos.TodosListView` is a CollectionView, similar to the menu in the jQuery UI example. `Todos.TodoView` is a Checkbox.
This generates the following html:

```
<div class="ember-view todo-list ui-sortable" id="ember267">
    <div class="ember-view" id="ember284">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ember-view ember-checkbox todo" id="ember297">
            <label>
            <script type="text/x-placeholder" id="metamorph-1-start"></script>
            something to do
            <script type="text/x-placeholder" id="metamorph-1-end"></script>
            </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to be able to do is edit the `<div>` that wraps the `<input>`. Assuming the todo's id is 1, I want to add `serial=todos_1`. I tried to add `didInsertElement` to `TodoView` and add an attribute to the parent view, but I didn't have access to the content of the view (the todo itself).

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
I found a workaround - adding the ID to the DOM as a hidden element.
The updated template:

```
{{#collection Todos.TodosListView}}
    {{#view Todos.TodoView contentBinding="content" checkedBinding="content.isDone" serial="content.serial"}}
        <label>{{content.title}}</label>
        <span style="display: none;" class="todo-id">{{content.id}}</span>
    {{/view}}
{{/collection}}
```

Todos.TodoView.didInsertElement:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var $div = this.get('parentView').$();
    var id = $div.children('.todo-id').text();
    $div.attr('serial', 'todos_' + id);
}
```

Generated html:

```
<div class="ember-view todo-list ui-sortable" id="ember267">
    <div class="ember-view" id="ember284" serial="todos_100">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ember-view ember-checkbox todo" id="ember297">
            <label>
                <script type="text/x-placeholder" id="metamorph-1-start"></script>
                something to do
                <script type="text/x-placeholder" id="metamorph-1-end"></script>
            </label>
            <span class="todo-id" style="display: none;">
                <script type="text/x-placeholder" id="metamorph-2-start"></script>
                100
                <script type="text/x-placeholder" id="metamorph-2-end"></script>
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would still like to know if there's a more elegant way of achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a computed property `serial` and add this property to the `attributeBindings` (documented [here](http://emberjs.com/#toc_attribute-bindings-on-a-view)) of your `itemViewClass` of `Todos.TodosListView`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/6X4QU/:

```js
Todos.TodosListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        attributeBindings: ['serial'],

        serial: function() {
            return 'todos_' + Ember.getPath(this, 'content.id');
        }.property('content.id').cacheable()
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is almost what I need... That way a `serial` attribute is added to the `<input>` tag (`TodoView` is `Em.Checkbox`), but the sortable items are the `<div>` elements. I could set the sortable items to be the `<input>` elements, but `<input>` doesn't include the label.

Comment: OK, then you have to define it on the `itemViewClass` of your `Todos.TodosListView`. I've update the answer and the corresponding JSFiddle. Is this what you wanted?